# Read a file in another subproject using Paths.get

Tags: java, gradle, build

I have two Gradle subprojects called X and Y. The Y subproject contains a java plugin that I have written. I want to load that plugin using a method I've written in a class which is located in the X subproject using `Paths.get()`.

Comment: Add some more explanation and code if possible!

Comment: Hello, thanks, I Edited the question. Hopefully, it provides enough information now.

Comment: I was thinking if i could add all the generated .class files from every plugin to a common folder then that would solve the issue. Any guidance regarding that ??

Comment: I was in a duty of reviewing a number of stackoverflow questions from new users if they fit this stackoverflow rules. But I dont know the solution to your question!

Comment: For anyone following up i found the solution in the following tutorial provided by oracle. https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Comment: For anyone following up i found the solution in the following tutorial provided by oracle. docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html

Answer (score 0):

This is from the oracle documentation.use

```
Path p1 = Paths.get("/home/logfile");
// Result is file:///home/logfile
System.out.format("%s%n", p1.toUri());
```

make sure you give the relative path from the class path or else give an absolute path.
Link to the documentation https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/pathOps.html